# Python plot of points, each of different color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib in python takes sequences of `x` and `y` values to produce a plot of data.

We can specify a color for the particular graph being plotted. However, since we are plotting an explicit list of dots, I wonder if there is a way to specify the color for each point individually?

For example, how can I make the points plotted in the following graph each have a specific random color?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('A single color plot')
```

[image]

Comment: i don't see points

Comment: You're not plotting points, you plot a line. If you wanted to plot points you could use `ax.scatter`. If instead you want individual line segments to be colorized, you can use a `LineCollection` as shown e.g. in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051922/how-to-get-differents-colors-in-a-single-line-in-a-matplotlib-figure).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh, ok, I'm happy with a scatter plot, too, if it can take individual colors for each point. How should I do that?

Comment: `ax.scatter(x,y, c=np.random.rand(len(x), 3))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Wow, so simple! Thank you!!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I wonder why the `plot` command cannot take the same input? Since it requires a list of points to create line segments anyway, it could simply smoothly interpolate the given colors from point to point...

Comment: `plot` creates a `Line2D` object, which is optimized for fast drawing. It would be bad style to let the same command `plot` return different objects, depending on the input. That's why there is `LineCollection`, which can be used if different segments are supposed to have different properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the links and suggestions of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) in the comments, I pieced together the following solution for the case when a plot of line segments of different color is required.

Ideally, I would have wished each point to be of a particular color and the line segments to smoothly interpolate in the color-spectrum between these respective colors. But I guess, matplotlib is free software, so it's not too surprising that it does not have the most fancy features. Unless, of course, if it can be done, but I don't know how?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
xy = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.hstack([xy[:-1], xy[1:]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=np.random.rand(len(segments), 3))
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.set_title('A multi-color plot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Just for fun, doing more steps and creating a gradient "by hand", as [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) suggested, we can get e.g. something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
x = [0.]
while x[-1]<2 * np.pi :
    x.append(x[-1] +1/(100*np.sqrt(1+4*x[-1]*x[-1]*np.cos(x[-1]*x[-1])*np.cos(x[-1]*x[-1]))))
x = np.array(x)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
xy = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.hstack([xy[:-1], xy[1:]])
myColors = np.random.rand(len(segments), 3)
for i in range(len(segments)//10):
    for j in range(9):
        myColors[10*i+j+1] = myColors[10*i]+(myColors[10*(i+1)]-myColors[10*i])*(j+1)/10
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=myColors)
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.set_title('A multi-color plot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It can be done of course. You would divide each segment again into several shorter ones, each with a color interpolated between the two end point colors.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest oh, ok, I see. I was kind of hoping there would be an automatic blender of some sort, which would make the process simpler... I mean, ideally one would need a continuous color gradient, which is hardly feasible with discrete methods applied "by hand".